# Excel COUNTIF with non-contiguous named ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using a formula for Data Validation to hide used names like this: `=IF(COUNTIF(DrawUsed, [Players])>=1, "", [Players])`, where `DrawUsed` is a named range. The problem is that my table looks like this:

[image]

I need the `Blind Draw Team` columns to be the first parameter of the `COUNTIF`, since if a name is used in the first column, it should not be available for the third `Blind Draw Team` column. The issue is that this formula, with a named range defined `=Blind!$B$2:$B$27,Blind!$I$2:$I$27,Blind!$P$2:$P$27` results in nothing but `#VALUE!` errors.

I cannot define a contiguous range because the `Buyer` columns should *not* be dependent on the values of `Blind Draw Team`, and should not hide used names, either.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by defining 3 separate ranges and this formula:

```
=IF(
    OR(
        COUNTIF(BlindUsed1, [Players])>=1,
        COUNTIF(BlindUsed2, [Players])>=1,
        COUNTIF(BlindUsed3, [Players])>=1
    ),
    "", 
    [Players]
)
```

Returns for legibility's sake.

**Update**

Solution 2: `INDIRECT` can handle non-contiguous ranges. I had a range that was literally just a bunch of noncontiguous cells. I defined it like this:

```
=INDIRECT(
    {
        "Sunday!$F$7",
        "Sunday!$F$15",
        "Sunday!$F$23",
        "Sunday!$F$31",
        "Sunday!$F$39",
        "Sunday!$M$7",
        "Sunday!$M$15",
        "Sunday!$M$23",
        "Sunday!$M$31",
        "Sunday!$M$39",
        "Sunday!$T$7",
        "Sunday!$T$15",
        "Sunday!$T$23",
        "Sunday!$T$31",
        "Sunday!$T$39"
    }
)
```

Then `COUNTIF` works on the range: `=COUNTIF(SundayCaptains,[Player])`. The only con with this method is the values won't update if you rename the worksheet.

Comment: Just curious, did you format that here, or have some program/software that "exploded" it out for you? I like it!

Comment: @BruceWayne I formatted it here. Excel formulas can be so hard to read, lol.